# how to access to database since another pc's? (in any place)

Tags: c#, connection, connection-string, database-connection

well I need to do 2 applications, one to users registers theirself (where the server is) and the another application is for the administrador can see who has register, but he doesn't have time to go (where the server is) so he need watch the information since other place, I haven't could do it,  my another idea is using web services, but i dont know how to public the web service in internet for consum it since anothers pc's, then for application 2, how will be the connection string?  i thoung with ip, but in [what is your ip address](http://www.whatismyip.com/) i watched the ip is dinamic, and it change with turn on the computer (where is the server), then, how can i do it? (i coulnd't to have a connection with ip, and i couldn't with name of computer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [heavily edited - hope I maintained the spirit] I want to use a web service, but I don't have a great way to connect to it.  I thought about using the IP address, but the IP address is dynamic

If you have servers that must remain available, they must be registered in some form of hostname lookup service, such as DNS.  Most people do this by maintaining a corporate intranet, using a hosting service to serve their database/application, or using a dynamic DNS service such as DynDNS.

> [heavily edited...] I need two applications, one for users to register themselves, and the other for the administrator to see who has registered, without going to the server...

**If this information is just for humans to read:**

You could simply create a shared source of this information, such as an internal Wiki, or an Excel document on a Windows network share, or Microsoft Sharepoint site, and let users write new entries to it.  The admin would simply read that document to find out the information.  This is much more light-weight, and could be reused for many other purposes.

There is a lot of existing free wiki/CMS software you could install and use for this purpose.

**If you need this to be accessible by other programs, rather than just human readers:**

You'll have to make some sort of database, and possibly a web service to access it.  Unfortunately, you'll need a lot more information for anyone to give you a good answer for these needs.  Any answer will make a lot of assumptions, and might put you in a bad spot in terms of scalability, performance, security, or reliability.

Some basic questions to get you started (certainly not a complete list) - How many users?  Where will they be located with respect to your servers (both this application you are writing, and the servers that the application seems to provide information about)?  How safe must the information be?  How much data?  But even with this data, it is hard to recommend any sort of application design or network topology without knowing all of your requirements.

If you need this to be reliable and secure (e.g. you're supporting more than just yourself and a couple users), you'll probably need to turn this into a serious project, and devote business research, design, development, and IT resources to it.  These resources can all be one person, but you should really go through all the motions if you don't want it to be an unmaintainable, insecure mess.